# Advanced Custom Fields - front-end form, save title from another field?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress's [Advanced Custom Fields 5](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin to create a front-end form. I would like to save the post title as one of the fields on my form. For example, one of my form fields is 'name' so I would like the post title to be 'John Smith'.

Looking at the [ACF documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/filters/acf-pre_save_post/) it gives example code (copied below) where pre_save_post can be hooked into achieve this. Hoewver, I have included this function and the title still fails to save. 
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
function my_pre_save_post( $post_id )
{
    // check if this is to be a new post
    if( $post_id != 'new' )
    {
        return $post_id
    }

    // Create a new post
    $post = array(
        'post_status'  => 'draft' ,
        'post_title'  => $_POST['fields']['field_123'] ,
        'post_type'  => 'post' ,
    );  

    // insert the post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post ); 

    // return the new ID
    return $post_id;
}

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_post', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: add a string in place of $_POST['fields]['field_123'], if that works the $_POST value is the issue, var_dump the $_POST in your form action to see what name it has.

Answer (score 0):

I am using exactly the same method and it works fine.

Just a note that `field_123` in your example is not the user defined field name in the wp back end but its actually the field name assigned in the `meta_key` value in the `wp_postmeta` table of you db.